# set up postgres users, roles and databases for rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, postgresql-9.1, rails-postgresql, pg

This really has me stuck, I'm a bit of a noob trying to use postgres for rails 4

I have postgres installed:

```
$ psql --version
psql (PostgreSQL) 9.1.10
contains support for command-line editing
```

`$ sudo apt-get install libpq-dev` worked fine

I have `gem 'pg'` in my gemfile

My `config/database.yml` looks like so:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: myafricastyle_development
  host: localhost
  pool: 5
  username: myafricastyle
  password: myafricastyle
```

Create the database: `$ sudo -u postgres createdb myafricastyle_development`

Here are the databases:

```
$ psql
psql (9.1.10)
Type "help" for help.

jasonshark=# \l
                                           List of databases
           Name            |   Owner    | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |   Access privileges   
---------------------------+------------+----------+-------------+-------------+-----------------------
 jasonshark                | jasonshark | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
 myafricastyle_development | postgres   | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
 postgres                  | postgres   | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
 template0                 | postgres   | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
                           |            |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1                 | postgres   | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
                           |            |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
(5 rows)
```

But then when I try to set it up inside the rails project directory I get this:

```
$ rake db:create:all
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "myafricastyle"
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "myafricastyle"
```

**Edit:**
This is my `pg_hba.conf` file:

```
local   all             postgres                                md5

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     md5
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
#local   replication     postgres                                md5
#host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32            md5
#host    replication     postgres        ::1/128                 md5
```

Though when I made my edits I did `sudo gedit pg_hba.conf` so the folder looks kinda funky:

```
/etc/postgresql/9.1/main$ ls
environment  pg_hba.conf   pg_ident.conf    start.conf
pg_ctl.conf  pg_hba.conf~  postgresql.conf
```

What can I change?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the user:

```
sudo -u postgres createuser myafricastyle
```

After creating the user you would also need to edit the pg_hba.conf file, as documented here:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html

Comment: Okay i created a user with that command (not superuser, allowed to createdb and not allowed to create new roles) but I get the same `password authentication failed` error

Comment: The user 'myafricastyle' should own the database, not 'postgres'. You have to create a new role for 'myafricastyle' that includes the right to create databases. Then, let 'myafricastyle' create the table 'myafricastyle_development'.

Comment: To clarify:
`sudo su - postgres`
  
    `create role myafricastyle with createdb login password 'myafricastyle'`
  
    `createdb -O myafricastyle myafricastyle_development`